# Suscribe to expiration access token

Tags: javascript, client, token, refresh

I want implement in Javascript client a function that when the access token expires auto refresh with the refresh token, I have multiple access tokens, how I can implement this?

I think in use a `setTimeout` but I think that I can't have multiples `setTimeouts`, so I think in a way to suscribe to the expiration date, but I don't know if is the correct approach, somebody do this before? Any idea? Thanks.

This is my code:

```
const expirationdDate = parsedToken.expiresAtInEpochSeconds;
  const nowDate = Date.now() / 1000;
  const timeUntilRefresh = expirationdDate - nowDate;

  if ( timeUntilRefresh > 0) {
    // setTimeout(() => {
    //   this.refreshTokens(audience);
    // }, timeUntilRefresh); ???
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a map for tokens.

```
{
   key : token_id,
   value : (token_id) => { 
           setTimeout(()=> delete tokenMap[token_id], expiry_timeout)
       }
}
```

Now when you don't find the token you requested from tokenRefreshMap i.e. when token was removed from map when it timed out, you can get a new token id back into the map with new timeout.